# При передаче корректной url строки по инициализатору URL(string: urlString) возвращает nil. Как исправить?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

При передаче корректной url строки по инициализатору URL(string: urlString) возвращает nil. Как исправить? При вводе значения из одного слова (Например Moscow) все работает, когда вводится город из двух слов я разделяю запрос с помощью split(separator: " ") и соединяю с помощью .joined(separator: "%20") и получаю город разделенный %20 и все, сразу нил. Как то можно решить эту проблему?

[image: строка юрл сформировани. Ключ скрыл по понятным причинам]

[image: получаем нил]

Answer (score 0):

Где-то у вас там есть некорректный для URL символ.
Пользуйтесь для кодирования **всех** параметров правильной функцией во избежание подобных проблем.

```
let city = "New York".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
print("http://site.com?key=113&q=\(city)")
print(URL(string:"http://site.com?key=113&q=\(city)")!)
```

*Output*

> http://site.com?key=113&q=New%20York
>   http://site.com?key=113&q=New%20York

Comment: К сожалению это не сработало, все равно в url получаю nil

Comment: Ищите что неверно в ссылке, скопируйте значение и пробуйте в браузере открыть. Еще как вариант, попробуйте NSURL(string:string).